# Jenkins pipeline configuration is giving HEAD" returned status code 128: stdout: stderr: fatal: cannot exec 'ssh': Too many levels of symbolic links

Tags: git, github, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

My Jenkins job pipeline configuration is giving below error.

Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h remote_url HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: fatal: cannot exec 'ssh': Too many levels of symbolic links
fatal: unable to fork

It was working fine till yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is an issue on the remote server side, queried by `git ls-remote`.

If that server is under your (or your organization control), check the `sshfs` service, as [in this issue](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/17545#issuecomment-786988861).

> You should be able to have the host key added to the ssh known_hosts file by becoming root and either using `ssh` to log into the host in question or establishing connection using `sshfs` from the command line (as `root`).
> You should be ask if you want to add it.